# NodeJS nodemailer - IIS SMTP Virtual Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, iis, nodemailer

I'm trying to use `nodemailer` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer) to send e-mail using a local windows server we have, with an SMTP Virtual Server.

The SMTP Virtual Server works fine, we already use Jmail in Classic ASP, pass it the server name, and email gets sent.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var options = {
    host: 'SERVERNAME'
};
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(options);
var email = {
    from: 'no-reply@domain.co.uk',
    to: 'webmaster@domain.co.uk',
    subject: 'hello',
    text: 'hello world!'
};
var callback = function(err, info){
    if (err) { throw err }
    console.log('sent');
}
transporter.sendMail(email, callback);
```

The error I get back from this is:

> Can't send mail - all recipients were rejected: 550 5.7.1 Unable to
>   relay for webmaster@domain.co.uk

If I update the `options` object to include `auth`, like this:

```
var options = {
    host: 'SERVERNAME',
    auth: {
        user: '...',
        pass: '...'
    }
};
```

I get this error:

> Invalid login: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type

How can I use `nodemailer` to send e-mail using our IIS SMTP Virtual Server..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why the above doesn't work, pointing `nodemailer` to our SMTP Virtual Server. However I've worked around it.

Our SMTP Virtual Server is setup to use our Office 365 account, so I've updated my `nodemailer` code to go to Office 365 direct, rather than via our local server.

```
var options = {
    host: 'SMTP.office365.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: false,
    ignoreTLS: false,
    auth: {
        user: '...',
        pass: '...'
    },
    tls: {
        ciphers: 'SSLv3'
    }
}
```

This works.